# Cargar txt o dat a Estructura de Datos en c++

Tags: c++, array, archivo, struct, fopen

Estoy tratando de poder cargar datos de un txt o dat a un array de estructuras. El poder guardar los datos en un archivo txt ya lo realicé utilizando la función fprintf, y todas las operaciones ya están listas, solo me falta el poder cargar los datos pero no encuentro una idea muy clara de como hacerlo. La estructura tiene diferentes tipos de datos y no se como podría asignar cada uno a una variable diferente. Por el momento le pus el tamaño final a 3 pero este puede ser extensible. Tenia una idea de que al momento de cargar cada dato vaya iterando también el i, aunque como digo, no tengo claro el hacerlo con ficheros.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define _maxSize 3

    using namespace std;

    struct tool{

        int registro;
        char nombre[20];
        int cantidad;
        float precio;
    };

    void menu(){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ MENU DE CREACION Y MANEJO DE ARCHIVOS ]\n\n";
        cout<<"[1]. Creacion del archivo y/o cargue del archivo\n";
        cout<<"[2]. Cargar el inventario existente en el archivo al sistema\n";
        cout<<"[3]. Ingresar Herramienta\n";
        cout<<"[4]. Mostrar Herramientas\n";
        cout<<"[5]. Guardar Cambios - Salir\n";
        cout<<"\nIngresa opcion : ";
    }

    void IngresarHerramientas(struct tool [],int );
    void mostrarHerramientras(struct tool [],int );

    int main(){


        //* ITERADOR PRINCIPAL
        int i = 0;
        
        int j,decidir,opc;
        bool creado = false,salir = false;

        FILE *miArchivo;    
        struct tool herramienta[_maxSize];
    
        do{
            menu();
            cin>>opc;
            switch (opc)
            {
            case 1:
                if(!creado){
                    creado = true;
                    miArchivo = fopen("miPrimerArchivo.txt","w");
                    printf("\n[ Acabas de crear el TXT ]\n\n");
                }else{
                    cout<<"\n\n\t\t[EL ARCHIVO YA FUE CREADO ]\n\n";
                }
                system("pause");
                break;

            case 2:

                break;


            case 3:
                    if(creado && i < _maxSize){
                        fopen("miPrimerArchivo.txt","a");
                        IngresarHerramientas(herramienta,i);
                        fprintf(miArchivo,"%i\n",herramienta[i].registro);
                        fprintf(miArchivo,"%s\n",herramienta[i].nombre);
                        fprintf(miArchivo,"%i\n",herramienta[i].cantidad);
                        fprintf(miArchivo,"%.2f\n",herramienta[i].precio);
                        i++;
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ SE INTRODUJERON LOS VALORES ]\n\n";
                        
                        fclose(miArchivo);
                    }else{
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ AUN NO SE CREO EL ARCHIVO ]\n\n";
                    }
                    system("pause");
                break;


            case 4:
                mostrarHerramientras(herramienta,i);
                break;

            case 5:
                cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ ARCHIVO GUARDADO Y CERRADO CORRECTAMENTE ]\n\n";
                cout<<"REVISE DOCUMENTO PORFAVOR...\n\n";
                fclose(miArchivo);
                salir = true;
                break;

            }

        }while(salir != true);



        return 0;
    }


    void IngresarHerramientas(struct tool herramienta[],int i){

        cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ INGRESO DE HERRAMIENTA N. -> "<<i<<" ]\n\n";


        herramienta[i].registro = i;
        
        cout<<"Ingresa el nombre de herramienta : ";
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(herramienta[i].nombre);
        
        cout<<"Ingresa la cantidad : ";
        cin>>herramienta[i].cantidad;

        cout<<"Ingresa el valor : ";
        cin>>herramienta[i].precio;

    }

    void mostrarHerramientras(struct tool herramienta[],int max){

        int i;

        cout<<endl;

        if(max != 0){
            
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ MOSTRANDO REGISTROS ]\n\n";
            for(i = 0; i < max; i++){

                cout<<"[txtos de Registro -> "<<i+1<<"]\n";
                cout<<"Numero de Registro : "<<herramienta[i].registro<<endl;
                cout<<"Nombre de Herramienta : "<<herramienta[i].nombre<<endl;
                cout<<"Cantidad Exacta : "<<herramienta[i].cantidad<<endl;
                cout<<"Precio Total  : "<<herramienta[i].precio<<endl<<endl;
                

            }

        }else{
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t[ NO SE ENCUENTRAN REGISTROS ]\n\n";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Y tu pregunta es? @AlexSantiago

Comment: Como cargar los datos de un archivo de texto a una estructura

Comment: Usando `fread`? `fscanf`? Depende de como esten almacenados.
Si la pregunta es esa lo que tu quieres es un tutorial.